# Modelling a relationship using ER diagram

Tags: entity, entity-relationship, relationship, erd

I am working Entity Relationship Diagram for my project... I am trying to represent the below lines in to my Entity Relationship Diagram-

```
An amtrak serves many cities, and a city may have multiple amtraks.
```

I am not able to post my image here with the solution I have as it needs atleast 10 reputation and which I don't have.

Can anyone tell me how we can represent the above relationship using ER diagram?

I was thinking of using One to Many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a [many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

Comment: Thanks Paul.. But what about `and a city may have multiple amtraks.` There is may written over there, so still it will be many to many relationship?

Comment: 'May' says the relation is optional.  It's zero to many instead of one to many on that side of the relationship.  It's still a many to many which is usually implemented as a relation table.  With zero you just have no row in the table for that city.  With one to many you always have at least one row for the city in the table.